# Did Humans and Minbari merge into a single "first-one like" species?

Tags: babylon-5

In one episode we see that humans have evolved into first ones like beings. Can't remember where I read it but apparently Minbari also evolve into first ones like beings.

We know that Minbari souls are being born into human bodies, and some human DNA exists in some Minbari.

In the episode where we see a first ones like human the ship he departs in has the logo of the rangers on it.

I know that there's been some B5 novels released but I've no idea if any are considered canon.

If there any evidence (canon or non-canon) that humans and Minbari merged into a single species over time?

Comment: You are referring to [4x22: "The Deconstruction of Falling Stars"](https://babylon5.fandom.com/wiki/The_Deconstruction_of_Falling_Stars). What you describe is its framing story/final scene.

Comment: There are certain other interesting questions this raises but impossible to answer from canon.  Specifically was there something about hybridization that allowed human and minbari to ascend but not other species?  I won't get into fan fiction on ascending. Also there is something going on in the babylon 5 universe that likes hybrids- the Hyach in season 5 are having a genome breakdown population decline because their equivalent of Neanderthals went extinct.   The Minbari population decline was unexplained until they decided it must be because humans were dipping into the minbari soul well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No.** JMS, when commenting on the million years in B5, discusses the Minbari and Humans as separate species still. Though we don't know - if we assume the descendants of Sheridan and Delenn are human, it will make a hybrid population of humans just as the Minbari (but not all) already are a hybrid population from Valen.

Also it is almost certain that Catherine Saki went back to Valen but unknown if she also transformed. We do know the pure Minbari were offended by Valen's descendants and they went into hiding. And it is virtually impossible they knew Valen's true nature so it must be because of his wife.

There also could be a third population from further Minbari/Human hybrids now that Valen and Delenn made it possible, but that would be entirely speculative.

> **Did the future humans leave the galaxy as the Vorlons did?**
>
> "No point in leaving the galaxy; stars go nova, it only affects the immediate vicinity (big as that is). By this point, they were in the position of the Vorlons, and now have to take their (our) place guiding the younger races, the next wave, while not getting in the way and remembering the lesson of the shadow/vorlon conflict."
>
> **What about the other races?**
>
> "The Minbari eventually make it; the Narn and Centauri do not. They don't die out, they just don't hit a state of First One-ishness, which is darn close to"
>
> [**JMS speaks**](http://www.midwinter.com/lurk/guide/088.html)